# More modern / correct model for mediation analysis than Baron & Kenny

Tags: logistic, mediation

What we found in our paper was that, after controlling for a bunch of other covariates X, the treatment T determine the outcome Y through the mediator M, with M fully mediating the relationship (after controlling for X).

In order to prove mediation, we used the Baron & Kenny model[1].
In particular, we regressed (1) Y on X and T, founding a significant coefficient for T (2) T on X and M, finding a significant coefficient for M, and (3) Y on X, T and M (same as 1, but we added M), finding a significant coefficient for M and a non significant coefficient for T.

The paper came back from peer review. The reviewers said the baron & Kenny model is outdated, and some consider this model outright wrong, and suggested us to use a different model.

What more modern / correct models are there for mediation analysis than Baron & Kenny model?

[1] Baron, R.M., Kenny, D.A., 1986. The Moderator-Mediator Variable Distinction in Social Psychological Research. Conceptual, Strategic, and Statistical Considerations. Journal of Personality and Social Psychology 51, 1173–1182. https://doi.org/10.1037/0022-3514.51.6.1173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [PROCESS macro](https://www.processmacro.org/index.html).

> PROCESS is an observed variable OLS and logistic regression path analysis modeling tool. It is widely used through the social, business, and health sciences for estimating direct and indirect effects in single and multiple mediator models (parallel and serial) , two and three way interactions in moderation models along with simple slopes and regions of significance for probing interactions, and conditional indirect effects in moderated mediation models with a single or multiple mediators or moderators.